# Common factors in ARIMA(p,d,q)

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

I have some concerns regarding interpreting ARIMA processes,
A general ARIMA process is on the form 
$$ \phi(B)X_t = \theta(B)Z_t,\,\,Z_t\sim WN(0,\sigma^2)$$

For example if I have $$Y_t = (1-B)^{12}X_t$$
and 
\begin{align*}
(5 + 6B + B^2)Y_t & = (5+B)Z_t \\
(5+B)(1+B)Y_t & = (5+B)Z_t
\end{align*}
Can one cancel out $5 + B$ ? so that $Y$ becomes a ARMA(1,0) process which is invertible but not causal ?
$$(1+B)Y_t=Z_t$$
and $X$ will be a ARIMA$(1,12,0)$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this follows from a general property of backshift operators provided (in your case) that $(1+B)Y_1=Y_1+Y_0=Z_1$.